# how can I speed up simultaneous read and write of multiprocessing queues?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

**tl;dr** - is there a way to increase the speed of simultaneously reading and writing to a multiprocessing queue?

I have an app that processes audit data.  Think of it like a syslog relay.  It receives data, parses it, then sends the event onward.  The event rate could be significant - I'm shooting for 15,000 events per second (EPS).

`in_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()`

`out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()`

- **ReaderProc** - single proc, socket reader, receives data and places it into `in_queue` using `in_queue.put()`
- **ParserProcs** - multiple procs, uses `in_queue.get()` to get data, processes the data, then places finished result in to `out_queue` using `out_queue.put()`
- **WriterProc** - single proc, reads `out_queue` using `out_queue.get()` and send data onwards via TCP socket connections

I ran tests using Queues - I can place *OR* pull events into a Queue at 25,000 EPS.  The slow-down occurs when multiple parsing processes (4) pull data off the queue as it is being written to.  The rate dips down to sub-10,000 EPS.  I'm guessing the underlying pipes, locks, etc. are the cause for the delay.

I read up on pipes and it looks like it only supports 2 endpoints.  I need to fork off the CPU-intensive parsing to multiple procs.  Can alternative methods like multiprocessing memory sharing achieve better results?  How can I get better simultaneous `.put()` and `.get()` operations from a Queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your performance needs, I think you'd be better off using a third-party message broker like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for this. I found a benchmark comparing multi[here](http://taotetek.net/2011/02/03/python-multiprocessing-zeromq-vs-queue/) (though it doesn't quite match your use-case). The difference in performance is enormous:

**multiprocesing.Queue Results**

```
1
2
3

python2 ./multiproc_with_queue.py
Duration: 164.182257891
Messages Per Second: 60907.9210414
```

**0mq Results**

```
1
2
3

python2 ./multiproc_with_zeromq.py
Duration: 23.3490710258
Messages Per Second: 428282.563744
```

I took both of those tests, and provided a more complicated workload, since one of the benefits of `multiprocessing.Queue` is that it handles serialization for you. Here's the new scripts:

**mult_queue.py**

```
import sys
import time
from  multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker(q):
    for task_nbr in range(1000000):
        message = q.get()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    send_q = Queue()
    Process(target=worker, args=(send_q,)).start()
    msg = {
            'something': "More",
            "another": "thing",
            "what?": range(200),
            "ok": ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']
            }
    for num in range(1000000):
        send_q.put(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = 1000000 / duration

    print "Duration: %s" % duration
    print "Messages Per Second: %s" % msg_per_sec
```

multi_zmq.py

```
import sys
import zmq
from  multiprocessing import Process
import time
import json
import cPickle as pickle

def worker():
    context = zmq.Context()
    work_receiver = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    work_receiver.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

    for task_nbr in range(1000000):
        message = work_receiver.recv_pyobj()

    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    Process(target=worker, args=()).start()
    context = zmq.Context()
    ventilator_send = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    ventilator_send.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
    msg = {
            'something': "More",
            "another": "thing",
            "what?": range(200),
            "ok": ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']
            }
    for num in range(1000000):
        ventilator_send.send_pyobj(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    msg_per_sec = 1000000 / duration

    print "Duration: %s" % duration
    print "Messages Per Second: %s" % msg_per_sec
```

Output:

```
dan@dan:~$ ./mult_zmq.py 
Duration: 14.0204648972
Messages Per Second: 71324.3110935
dan@dan:~$ ./mult_queue.py 
Duration: 27.2135331631
Messages Per Second: 36746.4229657
```

Comment: I saw that this test was a little [unfair](http://taotetek.net/2011/02/03/python-multiprocessing-zeromq-vs-queue/#comment-50) because of serialization/pickling.

I will do some more research, thank you for the response!

Comment: I actually tried this out myself, and zmq was still faster, though you should try it with your message payload and see what happens. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: very impressive results.  first two tests used your exact code.  last two used my long strings as messages.  strings seem to serialize/pickle very fast with zeromq.

queue_speed.py 
Duration: 31.4633660316
Messages Per Second: 31782.9948326

queue_speed_zmq.py 
Duration: 41.1004679203
Messages Per Second: 24330.6232411

queue_speed_long_string.py     
Duration: 28.4459819794
Messages Per Second: 35154.3497681

queue_speed_zmq_long_string.py 
Duration: 14.816603899
Messages Per Second: 67491.8494695

Comment: More results, this time using my out_queue, which is a dict.  zmq was slower.

queue_speed_zmq_outqueue.py 
Duration: 65.6619861126
Messages Per Second: 15229.5119171

queue_speed_outqueue.py     
Duration: 43.4732539654
Messages Per Second: 23002.6489574